# Within a tableView is it possible to have both grouped and plain section

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was wondering if it was possible within a plain style tableView to have one of the sections with a grouped style?

Thanks
Stewart

Comment: It's impossible. Just create 2 `UITableView`'s with each of them taking half the size of the screen.

Comment: thought as much, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the better solution would be to have two UITableViews. I'm guessing that the data in these tables are different anyway, so this would be much more ideal approach.

Answer (score 1):

The style is applied to the entire `UITableView`.  You could theoretically get around this by having the first cell in a normal style table be another table view that has the grouped style, and then the remainder of the cells are as normal.  Or the first cells are normal, and the last cell is the grouped style tableview, depending on if you wanted the grouped style first or not

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not, because both of them are styles that apply to whole `UITableView` instance. What you can do is for example split your table into sections and use custom cells. It will take you some time, but it should work.